# LLVM compatibility with legacy libraries built with gcc

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, gcc, legacy

We need to integrate with another company's product. Their SDK is ancient and they're really not likely to update it any time soon, despite our continuous encouragement and nagging.

Their SDK provides libraries built with gcc 4.0.1 and Mac OS X 10.4u SDK, producing fat binary libraries of 32-bit intel and PPC.

I'm developing on Yosemite with the latest XCode, which obviously uses LLVM and we're currently targeting 10.8 to 10.10

I've managed to find and download the Mac OS X 10.4u SDK from Apple's Developer site.

Not surprisingly, running *gcc -v* in Yosemite shows that it reverts to LLVM: -

> Configured with:
>   --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer//usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn) Target:
>   x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0 Thread model: posix

Would it be possible to use LLVM and include the libraries and headers built with gcc 4.0.1 to develop an application under XCode and if so, what's the best way to approach this?

If that's not possible, should I download gcc 4.0.1 and have to revert to doing everything on the command line in 10.10, or would I be better to create a separate, older development environment (perhaps with something like Lion) under a VM and using gcc from there?